# Not finding field in polymorphic association with Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a polymorphic association (Class Table Inheritance) and I need use DQL to query entities of a specific child class wich can be done using "x INSTANCE OF Entity" in WHERE clause. Now I need to put conditions specific for that child class but I get this error:

"Class Person has no association named student_field_1"

Person = Parent Class

Employee = Child class

Student = Child class

is there any way yo cast of somehow tell Doctrine that the Person is actually a Student and to allow me to put Student fields in the WHERE?

Comment: How does your current (yml) schema look like?

Comment: can you post your query builder code? I also had the similar problem but I solved it somehow. Need to know if you are also having the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a "Mapped Superclass" would be more suited to what your trying to do as it doesn't require an explicit link between parent / child, its just simple inheritance.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses

With Class Table Inheritance your required to provide discriminator map that links the two entities through a key.

"The table of a child class should be linked to the table of a parent class through a foreign key constraint"

Comment: I dont see how the Mapped Superclass would help for the query. btw, I need to have those 3 tables since that is the way the db is right now

Answer (score 0):

If you're only querying students, then why don't you just do this?

```
SELECT s FROM Student s WHERE s.student_field_1 = ...
```

Comment: Its actually an association. For example: car.person (can be employee or student)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. There is a feature request for what you're asking: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-16

Comment: Yes Benjamin, that's the problem. The feature is not implemented. Any idea if there is any workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of any decent workaround... An unefficient & complicated one whould be to return all entities where `Entity.person INSTANCE OF Student` then manually filter out the returned entities. But in your situation, I think I'd rather check if I can refactor my model so that my entity directly has a Student relationship, instead of a Person.

Comment: And what about changing the relationship "dynamically" from Person (in mapping) to Student before executing the query? is it possible?

Comment: I found out that I could change the association mapping info using the ClassMetadata, but that took me to other problems (since I'm using the inverse side of the assoc) and I'm posting to http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-16 I hope someone help me there...

Comment: I think that this approach is the best if you want to introduce loads of weird bugs :-) Is it a big performance problem to further filter entities in PHP, after a first DQL query? You could hide this complexity behind a repository method, until this feature is implemented.